# Why does this Array return as Native Code instead of Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, autosuggest

I have an array titled autosuggest_results which is used for a Typeahead. When I input text into a form field, the autosuggest populates with information. However, I noticed when I entered "POP", I received an error "Cannot read property of length undefined"...I noticed if I enter other JavaScript method names (such as Push, concat) that the error occurs.

Why does the following return as "function pop() { [native code] }" when I enter "POP"? If I enter "Test" for example it returns "[object Object]"

**autosuggest_results[trim($(autosuggest_active_field).val()).toLowerCase()]**

Answer (score 0):

> after seeing more info in a comment just now

wherever `autosuggest_results` is declared, it NEEDS to be declared as an object, not an array

```
var autosuggest_results = {};
```

Your original code will then be fine

---

`autosuggest_results` is an ARRAY ... `autosuggest_results['pop']` is the pop **method** of an array ... i.e it is `autosuggest_results.pop` ... coercing a (native) method to a string results in something like the string

```
function pop() {
    [native code]
}
```

What you possibly want is

```
var arrayOfResults = autosuggest_results.filter(v => ~v.indexOf(trim($(autosuggest_active_field).val()).toLowerCase()))
```

arrayOfResults will be an array of items in `autosuggest_results` which include (anywhere in the string, not an exact match) the current value of

```
trim($(autosuggest_active_field).val()).toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Instead of completely refactoring my autosuggest code (which I added to the original post), what would you suggest I do to allow POP? The .results.length is where the error is returned in the if statement

Comment: not sure what you're on about, I haven't refactored anything ... your code is looking for words in the properties of `autosuggest_results`, whereas, you should be looking at the values in the `autosuggest_results`

Comment: Can you explain what arrayOfResults is doing? I don't think I can understand what should be returned

Comment: it's an array of strings from `autosuggest_results` that match the input value

Comment: Hmm for some reason the array is returning empty :/

Comment: What does the autosuggest array look like

Comment: the issue is, it looks like you may be using `var autosuggest_results = []` but populating it like `autosuggest_results['someword'] = 'somevalue'` or similar ... if, as you say `autosuggest_results` is an **Array**, then you should access it like an array ... `autosuggest_results[0]`, `autosuggest_results[1]` ... etc ... `autosuggest_results['someword']` is not how to use an array (you perhaps want `autosuggest_results` to be an Object instead)

Comment: further more, the auto suggestions are in a property of `autosuggest_results["somevalue"].results` - THAT's the array

Comment: Ah yes autosuggest_results is declared as an array "autosuggest_results = []"

Comment: `var autosuggest_results = {};` for a start

Comment: Oh wow...all I had to do was change autosuggest_results to {} and it works!!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!